# Generating appointments (date)

Tags: java, calendar

For an assignment for school I need to be able to “calculate” certain dates.

I have a number of contact moments that I need to auto assign to a certain date (day in the week) and print …

Let’s say from the first of January I need to assign every Monday to a contact moment except if this Monday is a holiday or so.  I have a list of valid days in my database in date format to check against.

What I have until now :

For the day I was thinking to start at a certain day and then add 7 day’s

I would set the date :

```
set(int year, int month, int date)
```

And then adding with 7 to go from week to week :

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
```

I would then check if this date equals a date in my mysql table.

```
compareDatesByCalendar(Date javaDate, Date mysqlDate) { 
    Calendar javaCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar mysqlCal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    javaCal.setTime(javaDate);
   mysqlCal.setTime(mysqlDate); 
    if (javaCal.equals(mysqlCal)) {
        ……..
    } 
else{
….}
```

If the day is not in the list I would just add 7 more and check again … .

So on until I have all the moments, adding on them to an array to print

Is this the right way to take this on or a better way?

Let’s say we want to make an appointment each Thursday, is there a way to see what is the first day from the starting point (for example starting from first January).?

What if there is a maximum of weeks (moments available)?  How could I block this?

Any suggestions would be more then helpfull!  Thx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will be focusing heavily on dates I would recommend you take a look at the [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) API. It offers more functionality than the standard DateTime Java API. You could take a look [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed [Lamma](http://lamma.io) which is designed to solve this use case.

```
    HolidayRule ukHoliday2015 = simpleHolidayRule(
            date(2015, 1, 1), date(2015, 4, 3), date(2015, 4, 6),
            date(2015, 5, 4), date(2015, 5, 25), date(2015, 8, 31),
            date(2015, 12, 25), date(2015, 12, 28)
    );

    List<Date> dates = Dates.from(2015, 12, 23).to(2015, 12, 30).byDays(2).except(weekends()).except(ukHoliday2015).build();

    for (Date date: dates) {
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

output is:

```
Date(2015,12,23)
Date(2015,12,29)
```